# VS Code Jupyter Extension source view

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I'm unable to open a Jupyter Notebook and see/edit the source JSON when the Jupyter extension is enabled. Is there an option or button somewhere to see the source JSON of an opened Jupyter notebook, or do i have to manually enable/disable the extension every time i want to see/edit the source code of the notebook?

Why is this an issue?
I want to find replace some code in a directory that contains multiple notebooks. I therefore want to see the source JSON of the notebook to copy the exact multiline string that i want to replace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Right click on an .ipynb file in the file explorer side bar to bring up the context menu.
2. In the context menu, select 'Open With'. This will bring up a quickpick.
   [image: Context menu]
3. In the quickpick, select 'Text Editor'. This should open your .ipynb as JSON.
   [image: Text editor]

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/5724

You can also press the gear icon (on the Text Editor) option to ensure that the file in question ALWAYS opens as JSON